# Swipe on UITableViewCell in iOS7 and didSelectRowAtIndex gets called!! How do i disable it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In iOS 7,when i swipe a cell,its `didSelectAction` is getting called.I don't want this.I just need that on cell tap!What do i do?
I tried fixing it by disabling  `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` in the class that contains the tableView

```
 [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
```

NOT WORKING.

Comment: I got rid of this by adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer in the customCell class.
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwiped:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
      UIPanGestureRecognizer *g = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint point = [g velocityInView:self];
         if (fabsf(point.x) > fabsf(point.y) )     return YES;  return NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS 7 and I prefer to not use it: Try to do:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```